# Microsoft Analysis - how to set dimension to show bit as True/False instead of 1/0

Tags: c#, ssas, olap-cube

I'm writing a program to process a cube using Microsoft Analysis, and I want
bit values to be shown as True/False whenever I browse the cube (lets say in Excel).

I've managed to show null values as some string using 'Unknown', but I can't figure how to do the same with the actual values.

P.S. I ***do not*** want to convert it by using a CASE query in the DSV table creation. I want it to be only at the Dimension level.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might "not want" to rely on a CASE statement in the DSV, but SSAS doesn't give you any other options to achieve what you want.  So hold your nose and start coding...

FWIW - I prefer a SQL View (rather than calculations in a DSV) for more re-use and easier testing.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I ran it again without trying to 'fix' the  bit-bool issue, and it somehow (and I hate using this word when it comes to programming) gave me what I've wanted - when I browse the cube the values are shown as True/False.

Comment: I would be suspicious of that - it's probably at the whim of your browsing tool.  Make sure you are using the same tools as your users.